# Remove seasonality from a given table

Tags: r, time-series

I am really new into R and I'm currently learning about Timeseries.
I have a given table that looks like this:

```
           2016 2017 2018 2019
Χειμώνας     1    2    2    1
Άνοιξη       3    2    4    3
Καλοκαίρι    6    7    8    8
Φθινόπωρο    4    5    5    6
```

What I am really trying is to plot that table and remove the seasonality. However I don't know how to do it in a given table. Is there any way I can plot that table and remove the seasonality?

Comment: You have far too few data points to even start thinking about seasonality. Check this topic: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/435065/time-series-decomposition-remove-seasonality

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using tidyverse packages.

0. Note that column names in R should not be numeric. It can be done but is best avoided for analysis, IMO. https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/make.names.html
1. reshape the data into longer form to make calculations simpler by group.
2. calculate the seasonally adjusted value by subtracting the seasonal average from each value. https://otexts.com/fpp3/classical-decomposition.html#additive-decomposition
3. make the seasons an ordered factor so that ggplot doesn't display them alphabetically
4. plot them with season as x, seasonally adjusted value as y, color/group by year.

---

```
df <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
            Season = c("Winter", "Spring", "Summer", "Fall"),
             x2016 = c(1L, 3L, 6L, 4L),
             x2017 = c(2L, 2L, 7L, 5L),
             x2018 = c(2L, 4L, 8L, 5L),
             x2019 = c(1L, 3L, 8L, 6L)
)

library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  pivot_longer(x2016:x2019, names_to = "year") %>%
  mutate(val_sa = value - mean(value), .by = Season) %>%
  mutate(Season = forcats::fct_inorder(Season)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Season, val_sa, color = year, group = year)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]